# Neural Network ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, error-handling, neural-network

I am currently trying to run a neural network to predict whether a given house is above or below the median housing value. I have six inputs which include square feet, number of bedrooms, number of bathrooms, number of garage spaces, etc. The response variable is a binary variable indicated whether the price is below (0) or above (1) the median sell price.

I am very new to neural networks, so I am just experimenting around trying to learn. I am following this tutorial: https://hackernoon.com/build-your-first-neural-network-to-predict-house-prices-with-keras-3fb0839680f4 but using different data. Here is a heading of my data:

```
Beds  Baths   SqFt   LotSize  Built   Garage   AboveMedianPrice
3     2.5     2336   0.050    2004    2        0.0
4     3.5     3430   0.069    1999    2        1.0
...
```

Here is how I went about setting up the neural network.

- Data Scaling

```
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler() #requires numeric values
X_scale = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X) #scales dataset so that all input features are in [0, 1].

#Partition the dataset between training and validation.
X_train, X_val_and_test, Y_train, Y_val_and_test = train_test_split(X_scale, Y, test_size=0.3)

#Seperates into seperate validation set and test set.
X_val, X_test, Y_val, Y_test = train_test_split(X_val_and_test, Y_val_and_test, test_size=0.5)

print(X_train.shape, X_val.shape, X_test.shape, Y_train.shape, Y_val.shape, Y_test.shape) ## output: (382, 6) (82, 6) (83, 6) (382,) (82,) (83,)
```

- Model Building

```
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Dense 

model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(6,)), #input shape is 6: one for each predictor variable
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', #sgd = stochastic gradient descent
              loss='binary_crossentropy', #binary = output values are 0 or 1
              metrics=['accuracy']) #metrics will track the accuracy of the loss function
```

Then, I try to run the model using the following code segment

```
hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
          batch_size=32, epochs=100,
          validation_data=(X_val, Y_val))
```

however, when the first epoch starts running, I receive a `ValueError` that I don't know how to fix. Here is more details about the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-7ee038121eec> in <module>
      4 #yVal = np.asarray(Y_val)
      5 
----> 6 hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
      7           batch_size=32, epochs=100,
      8           validation_data=(X_val, Y_val))

...

Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).
```

Is there something small that I am missing?

Comment: The problem is not in the neural network, X_train, Y_train, or X_val, Y_val have string values which are not valid as inputs to a neural network, make sure all inputs and targets are numbers.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy thank you. That did fix that, but it led me to another error. I am following this tutorial (but with different data) https://hackernoon.com/build-your-first-neural-network-to-predict-house-prices-with-keras-3fb0839680f4 . I now have a value error.